# Why I get error from pip installing getch?

Tags: python, pip

I'm doing a small file checker, and I need to do a (character pressed?) command. So I used getch. I get this error when trying to pip install it:

```
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\us
ers\\manolo\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-ehxrw3\\getch\\setup.py';exec(compi
le(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __fil
e__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\manolo\appdata\local\temp\pip-flekfr-re
cord\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed wi
th error code 1 in c:\users\manolo\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ehxrw3\getch
```

Can someone say to me how to fix this?

Also, I have python 2.7 running on win32, windows 7.

Comment: Have you had a look in the `install-record.txt`?

Comment: Nope. Wait a second.

Answer (score 0):

You can change getch for msvcrt, and it's pre-installed on Windows.